# How can I pass html back from a php include files switch/case statement

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I am using a href tag to change pages in the content area of my website. I am currently calling the content through a function and it works great. However whenever I run into content that has multiple figures, I am struggling to clear the content area and display a large image. I am trying to use a href tag to call a PHP file with a switch statement. Code is below. How can I get it to work?

**This is the calling portion in `ranch_signs.php`:**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="outlet-covers-item col-md-6">  
 <figure>
   <a href="?page=enlarge_image&?id=1"><img src="images/c-lazy-3.jpg" alt="Oval shape custom metal ranch sign"></a>
   <figcaption>
     <h4>Oval Shape Sign </h4>
     black finish<br> 
     custom metal sign <br>
     <a href="?page=enlarge_image&?id=2">Enlarge Images</a>
   </figcaption>
    </figure><br><br>
  </div>
  <div class="outlet-covers-item col-md-6">  
 <figure>
   <a href="?page=enlarge_image&?id=cl2"><img src="images/forman-mizpah.jpg" alt="Overhead custom metal ranch sign"></a>
   <figcaption>
  <h4>Overhead Ranch Sign </h4>
  custom metal sign <br>
  <a href="?page=enlarge_image&?id=cl2">Enlarge Images</a>
   </figcaption>
 </figure><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is the `enlarge_image.php`:**

```html
<?php switch ($id) { 
  case 1: ?>
    <figure>
   <img src="images/outlet-1.jpg" alt="Proud Stallion custom metal outlet cover">
   <figcaption>
     <h4>Proud Stallion</h4>
     black painted Outlet Cover<br>
     <a href="?page=outlet_covers">Shrink Images</a>
   </figcaption>
    </figure><br><br>
  <?php break; ?>
  
  <?php case 2: ?>
    <figure>
   <img src="images/outlet-2.jpg" alt="Bull Moose Copperized finish custom metal outlet cover">
      <figcaption>
     <h4>Bull Moose</h4>
     Copperized finish<br>
     <a href="?page=ranch_signs_enlarged">Shrink Images</a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure><br><br>
  <?php break; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Is there a way to get this code functional?

Comment: you have a typo: `&?id=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit it looks like you're assuming that the GET argument of `id` is just getting passed straight into PHP code and is accessible via `$id`.

You need to read this variable in through the input stream.

**The enlarge_image.php file should look like this:**

```
    <?php 

$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_INT); // This line reads in 'id' sent through the URL into the variable $id

switch ($id) { 
      case 1: ?>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/outlet-1.jpg" alt="Proud Stallion custom metal outlet cover">
          <figcaption>
            <h4>Proud Stallion</h4>
            black painted Outlet Cover<br>
            <a href="?page=outlet_covers">Shrink Images</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure><br><br>
      <?php break; ?>

      <?php case 2: ?>
        <figure>
          <img src="images/outlet-2.jpg" alt="Bull Moose Copperized finish custom metal outlet cover">
          <figcaption>
            <h4>Bull Moose</h4>
            Copperized finish<br>
            <a href="?page=ranch_signs_enlarged">Shrink Images</a>
          </figcaption>
        </figure><br><br>
      <?php break; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your addition in the in the same location and I get the following errors:  Notice: Use of undefined constant FILTER_SANITIZE_INT - assumed 'FILTER_SANITIZE_INT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\bcmw\includes\enlarge_image.php on line 2

Warning: filter_input() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\bcmw\includes\enlarge_image.php on line 2

Comment: I went back and found a mistake I made in trying to get the id to pass correctly last night. I had put question mark before my variable. When I removed the question mark and changed to FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING everything started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your links include an extra question mark "?" as a part of the URL; which I assume is incorrect and this means that your links are pointing to an incorrect location.

**E.g.:**

`<a href="?page=enlarge_image&?id=cl2">Enlarge Images</a>`

**I assume should be:**

`<a href="?page=enlarge_image&id=cl2">Enlarge Images</a>`

Comment: I took out the extra ? and I get 2 errors still.     Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\bcmw\includes\enlarge_image.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\bcmw\includes\enlarge_image.php on line 13

Comment: Okay, see my other question; I think I know what the problem is.